# stop all child processes when 1 of then returned exit code 1

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have 2 or more build processes to run in background. I want to stop all the build processes if one of them exit with code other than 0.

```
./build-1.sh &
./build-2.sh &
./build-3.sh &
wait
#other steps
```

Currently, I use `wait` which will need to wait all processes to finish. But if 1 of them failed, I want to stop all other build. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is commonly called a `named pipe` and is used for inter-process communication (IPC). There are some great docs abound about creating named pipes in Bash so I'll leave it to you to write up the code for that.

Once you have a named pipe in place, you could do something like write the PID of each of the processes to the pipe (using the Bash special variable `$$` for the current PID), and then have each sit in a loop checking for the existence of each of the PIDs. if it encounters one that no longer exists (the process died or was killed), then it can take an action.

You would put something like this in appropriate section of your script(s). Please test it first. :)

```
trap "rm -f $named_pipe" EXIT

# Assuming you have a file under $named_pipe with space-delimited PIDs
pids = $(< $named_pipe)
while :
do
  for pid in pids:
  do 
    if ! kill -0 $pid;
    then
      exit
    fi
  done
done
```